# How do I get the id of sortable element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using Sortable and got it up and working. But I'm trying to save what is where inside the lists.

Lets say i have 3 lists:

```
<ul id="top" class="connectedSortable">
<li>elem1</li>
<li>elem2</li>
<li>elem2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="left" class="connectedSortable">
</ul>

<ul id="right" class="connectedSortable">
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#top, #left, #right")
.sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function(event, ui)
    {
        alert(this.id); // printing top, left right...
    }
})
.disableSelection();
```

I've tried to use the `stop` event inside sortable but it only returns the `ul`'s id of course. So what I want is jQuery to tell me when I've moved `elem1` from `list1` to `list2` (or any `elemX` of course).

I'm trying to make a homepage that the user could define the layout themselves.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you want to use the [`receive`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) callback:

http://jsfiddle.net/nzskv/1/

```
$("#top, #left, #right").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        alert("[" + this.id + "] received [" + ui.item.html() + "] from [" + ui.sender.attr("id") + "]");
    }
}).disableSelection();
```